# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(ZZLandroidx/compose/ui/window/SecureFlagPolicy;ZILkotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to use Dialog android compose this code an i want the dialog full screen like this :

```
   Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = { },
        DialogProperties(
            usePlatformDefaultWidth = false,
            dismissOnBackPress = true,
            dismissOnClickOutside = false
        )
    )
```

Unfortunately this error appear :

```
   Process: com.app.app PID: 27584
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(ZZLandroidx/compose/ui/window/SecureFlagPolicy;ZILkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V in class Landroidx/compose/ui/window/DialogProperties; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties' appears in /data/app/~~eVwp2yK_fyWgL__UHhepqA==com.app.app-SKA9YfL5rl-chv6uDMdtgQ==/base.apk!classes21.dex)
```

Comment: Did you try modifying your `kotlin` and `compose` versions? or did you  `invalidate~restart` your IDE?, occasionally these steps fixes this type of problem

Comment: Thats usually a sign of depency conflict or that the lib you need require an update, check the build.graddle on your module.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/togisoft/jetpack_compose_country_code_picker

All problems have been fixed with the new update. You can check!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using this library:

`com.github.togisoft:jetpack_compose_country_code_picker`

This library calls internally the Dialog. On my build.gradle I just removed the material3 implementation:

`androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-beta03`

After I removed it started work properly again!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error in an initializer, and for me the problem was I had accidentally imported the java `forEach` method instead of the Kotlin `forEach`. Updating the import fixed it, I'm commenting here in case anyone else comes across this same error.